# How to use sed to find and replace string in mac terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I use Xcode. I want to use bash to batch modify the UI fonts.

For instance change:

```
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
```

to:

```
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="PingFangSC-Regular" family="PingFang SC" pointSize="12"/>`
```

Code to start:

```
 find . -type f    '(' -name '*.storyboard' -o -name '*.xib' ')' .  \
 -exec  sed -i '' s/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" type=\"system\" pointSize=\"17\"\/\>'/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" name=\"PingFangSC-Regular\" family=\"PingFang SC\" pointSize=\"12\"\/\>'/ {} +

 # placeholder, to look code better
```

This is the easy version. I want to find the number ( font size ) and replaced in the next string.

I have read [Using sed to find and replace complex string (preferrably with regex)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/using-sed-to-find-and-replace-complex-string-preferrably-with-regex) .

Thanks to @battlmonstr, I tried

```
find . -type f  '(' -name '*.storyboard' -o -name '*.xib' ')' \
-exec  sed -E -i '' 's@\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" type=\"system\" pointSize=\"17\"/>@<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" name=\"PingFangSC-Regular\" family=\"PingFang SC\" pointSize=\"12\"\/>@' {} +

#  placeholder
```

It is OK.

In order to test more , like

```
$ echo abcd123 | sed 's/\([a-z]*\).*/\1/'
abcd
```

I want to keep the number.

In order to get the number ,and then arrange the content to replace, I tried

```
$ echo "<fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>" |  \
sed -E  's@\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" type=\"system\" pointSize=\"(\d+)\"\/>@\1@'

<fontDescription key=fontDescription type=system pointSize=17/>
```

The result is not OK, not like the one above. Not expected.

I tested in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) which is OK. I'm still figuring why.

---

---

The example content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7yI-IF-sfh">
                                <rect key="frame" x="126" y="266" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="PingFangSC-Regular" family="PingFang SC" pointSize="12"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vTz-nw-d8Y">
                                <rect key="frame" x="126" y="416" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="PingFangSC-Regular" family="PingFang SC" pointSize="12"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VCU-bo-Iyu">
                                <rect key="frame" x="175" y="218" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="PingFangSC-Regular" family="PingFang SC" pointSize="12"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="O3R-uM-fzi">
                                <rect key="frame" x="91" y="217" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="PingFangSC-Regular" family="PingFang SC" pointSize="12"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="93Z-nX-mmW">
                                <rect key="frame" x="188" y="64" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="PingFangSC-Regular" family="PingFang SC" pointSize="12"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9O2-dY-2nt">
                                <rect key="frame" x="277" y="197" width="42" height="13"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="PingFangSC-Regular" family="PingFang SC" pointSize="12"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7Mp-RI-aG9">
                                <rect key="frame" x="69" y="87" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="PingFangSC-Regular" family="PingFang SC" pointSize="12"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <gestureRecognizers/>
                        <connections>
                            <outletCollection property="gestureRecognizers" destination="QsQ-yU-xmv" appends="YES" id="4co-bU-mXm"/>
                        </connections>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
                <pongPressGestureRecognizer allowableMovement="10" minimumPressDuration="0.5" id="QsQ-yU-xmv"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="53.600000000000001" y="26.53673163418291"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between the first and 2nd version you have replaced `-i ''` with `-E ''` which is likely causing this problem. You probably want to keep `-i`, and add `-E` before that like this:

```
sed -E -i '' ...
```

`''` is an argument to `-i` that basically tells "do not do backups".

What usually helps to find the problem is to debug "sed" separately from "find", e.g. run that sed command separately, without `find` and without in-place replacement, and hack until it works. Then add `-i` and `find` on top.

I recommend to start simple and work your way forward.
Simplify to this:

```
sed -E 's/pointSize="12"/pointSize="15"/'
```

Test that it works. Then improve it a bit:

```
sed -E 's/pointSize="[0-9]+"/pointSize="15"/'
```

Test that it works, etc.

Comment: I updated. Could you give me more tips? So I can get the number ,and  then arrange   the content to replace.

Comment: I recommend to start simple and work your way forward. Simplify to this:

    sed -E 's/pointSize="12"/pointSize="15"/'

Works? Yes. Then improve it a bit:

    sed -E 's/pointSize="[0-9]+"/pointSize="15"/'

Answer (score 1):

The actual code based on battlmonstr's answer.

```
find . -type f  '(' -name '*.storyboard' -o -name '*.xib' ')' -exec  \
sed -E -i '' 's@\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" type=\"system\" pointSize=\"([0-9]+)\"/>@<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" name=\"PingFangSC-Regular\" family=\"PingFang SC\" pointSize=\"\1\"\/>@' {} +

#
```

Firstly I try like this `echo "pointSize=\"11\"" | sed -E  's@\pointSize=\"([0-9]+)\"@poinize=\"\1\"@'`